# iOS Safari - Change select dropdown option font size with CSS?

Tags: css, ios, mobile, webkit, mobile-safari

I’ve read about a couple of hacks adding an option group with HTML - but I’m using a Shopify app for dropdowns so can only style with CSS.

Is there any way to change the font size or to stop the truncation of long options?

[image]